# Language selection in Panels?

Tags: panels, i18n-l10n

I have a panel node and in it I added a node. Is there any way to make Panels load the translation of the node based on the user current language. This is easy to do with Views adding a filter, but I can´t see how to do it with panels (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels should always respect the current users language, I've built several multilingual Panels sites, and never had to tell Panels which language to load.

In fact, the node "task handler", which is responsible for rendering nodes, doesn't even do a lot of work, but hands that responsibility over to Core, and as such, language to the Locale module.